# Svelte how to get text value after click on element ('li')?

Tags: svelte

how can i get text value in Svelte if i click on element ?

I need update variable if i click on element - li item.

my code :

```
<script>
    let languages = ['sk','cz','en','at']
    let activeLang = 'en'
</script>
<ul>
    {#each languages as language }
    <li on:click={activeLang = ???} >{language}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `on:click` give you back an `event` parameter. You can then with this one access the `innerText` of the `li` by using `event.target.innerText`.

So here in your example:

```js
<script>
    let languages = ['sk','cz','en','at']
    let activeLang = 'en'
</script>

<ul>
    {#each languages as language }
    <li on:click={(event) => activeLang = event.target.innerText} >{language}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

Have a look at the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ce544c0f9dd04c09b792ffe05c739910?version=3.38.3).

But since you already have the `language` variable that contains the needed information, just assign this one to `activeLang` on click inside of the callback:

```html
<script>
    let languages = ['sk','cz','en','at']
    let activeLang = 'en'
</script>

<ul>
    {#each languages as language }
    <li on:click={() => activeLang = language} >{language}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

See the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3bacd69b528b4e528a57f6f336cf372e?version=3.38.3).

Comment: Perfect @johannchopin, works correctly. Many thanks